# how to mopub ads add in application

Tags: android, ads, mopub

i want to add ads banner in my application i have integrate mopub sdk with my project and import and add library to the my project now my question is how to add banner disply and where code i have to write in my application java code and xml code about ads so please help enyone

my java code and mainifest file code is given below

mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.ration;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView web;
    int k;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        web=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://dcs-dof.gujarat.gov.in/live-info.htm");
//        web.getProgress();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0,1,menu.NONE,"About");
        menu.add(0,2,menu.NONE,"Feedback");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id=item.getItemId();
        if(id == 1)
        {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"About",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,about.class);
            startActivity(i);
         }
        else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Feedback",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent i2 =new Intent(MainActivity.this,feedback.class);
            startActivity(i2);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // .... other stuff in my onResume ....
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this,"Press Again to Exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
```

and my manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ration"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ration.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.ration.about"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.ration.feedback"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
        <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
/>

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better go through the guide for [Mopub Banner Ads Integration](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Banner-Integration) which explains you the steps of banner ads integration.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: hello dude....i refers it but i am little confuse about this code    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
    android:id="@+id/adview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
/>

Comment: @PranavLathigara What is your confusion ?

Comment: confusion about banner code where exactly write it in activity_main if there then my layout going to disturb ...?

Comment: How can you say that your layout will be disturbed ? Have think of where do you want to show the ads in your layout ? @PranavLathigara

Comment: I want to display it to the start of application.....if u have example then send it to me...plzz  thanx u very much

Comment: You mean to say you want to display it in launcher activity ?

Comment: At the top or at the bottom ?  I guess your mainactivity only contains the Webview right ?

Comment: Yes it contain only webview and i want to add full screen banner at starting and ending of application

Comment: Then i think you need to create a splash screen which contains only the mopub layout and you can show it for the 5 seconds only.

Comment: As i told you that you have to create separate activity for that like splash screen (hope you know about splash screen) and create a layout for that activity in which you can add the mopub  in full screen and start that activity as launcher.

Comment: Yes i hav full banner id which genarated on site but when i am create xml file for ads there geting class error like failed to instantiate.....

Comment: my banner activity code is given here please check it and tell me what is the problem in this code 



        private MoPubView moPubView;
    
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.banner_main);
      
      moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
            moPubView.setAdUnitId("554e6c47cad643fabca500df11cc1975");
            moPubView.loadAd();
            
            moPubView.setBannerAdListener(this);
      
            
    }

Comment: Have you added its jar file in your project ? Code is fine.

Comment: Yes i add mopub sdk and library in my project

Comment: What is the issue now ?

Comment: I have checked your code ,its showing some error in logcat that ads failed to load. Try to make your GPS on and then load.

Comment: i sent you a screenshot of my phone plz check it

Comment: Check for the link which is showing in your mopub to get the test ads. Exactly i don't know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use view in XML file

```
        <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
        android:id="@+id/mrect_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

in activity Load code

pass id of view in below function ,unit id of ur app,and keywords of cataogry of ads

```
           public void loadMoPubView(MoPubView moPubView, String adUnitId, String keywords) {
    if (moPubView == null) {
        Utils.logToast(LockScreenActivity.this, "Unable to inflate MoPubView from xml.");
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to inflate MoPubView from xml.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        Utils.validateAdUnitId(adUnitId);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        Utils.logToast(LockScreenActivity.this, exception.getMessage());
        return;
    }



    moPubView.setBannerAdListener(this);
    moPubView.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);
    moPubView.setKeywords(keywords);
    moPubView.setAutorefreshEnabled(true);
    moPubView.loadAd();


}
```